# SpriteKit - Sea Surface from above perspective with Swift in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, physics, surface

I want to implement a sea surface from above perspective for one of my games in iOS (with SpriteKit).

Basically like a relaxed sea, from above - subtle wave motion going around, with possible objects floating and reacting with the motion. As if you're flying from a plan, and looking down at the sea, and you can see a beach ball on the water surface, which is moving according to changes in the water.

I tried to search for libraries or guides since i assumed this would be popular thing, but sadly i could not find anything.

So i am asking for your help and guidance:

Is what i'm asking to do, complicated to implement? would love directions to guides or information about tools within iOS / SpriteKit so i can start from somewhere.

I would love to implement that sea engine myself, but - are there are external libraries that do such stuff?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Check out this project which replicates a water surface. https://github.com/ymc-thzi/ios8-spritekit-custom-shader/tree/master/ios8-spritekit-custom-shader

Comment: @sangony - that is absolutely incredible! I would love to see more stuff if people has to offer, but please post this as an answer so i can select it. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the offer but that would be a link only answer. If you are interested in a water container side view, check out this link http://www.free-pobo.com/animating-water-fragment-shader-ios8/

Answer (score 1):

This would not be very complicated if you want more of a cartoony feel for your game rather than real world physics.

What you can do is draw an ocean image or blue background and then have a few other images (little ripples of the water, beach ball, junk, etc) all at random locations. This will give the impression that you have an ocean with stuff in it.

Now for making the stuff float around, you can pick a direction you want your "wind" to go in and then loop through all of your objects and apply that force to them so they all look to be floating together.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Indeed i considered such an idea, however i'd really want to have real world physics, so ill try to see if i can get any suggestions regarding that.